# Powershell throws error Cannot perform operation because operation ReportWrongProviderType is not valid

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-agent

I have a powershell script that, when I run it from the powershell command line, it works fine.  However, when I run it via a SQL Server Agent Job it throws this error:

> A job step received an error at line 149 in a Powershell script.  The
>   corresponding line is 'if ($Datatable.Rows.Count > 0)'  Correct the
>   script and reschedule the job.  The error information returned by
>   PowerShell is 'Cannot perform operation because operation
>   "ReportWrongProviderType" is not valid.  Remove operation
>   "ReportWrongProviderType", or investigate why it is not valid.' 
>   Process Exit Code -1.

Powershell script throwing the error:

```
function Get-BackupHistory
{
    #module to gather all of the backup history data for the DBAdmin_Central database
    Write-Host "Get  Backup History"

    #query to get list of servers to run queries against - primary oltp's
    #this will run against the central management server
    $ServerQuery = 
    "
        select
            ss.PK_ServerID as id,
            ss.ServerName as name,
            isnull(bms.MaxMediaSetID, 0) as MaxMediaSetID,
            isnull(MaxBackupSetID, 0) as MaxBackupSetID
        from DBAdmin_Central.CentMang.SQLServers ss
            left outer join
            (
                select 
                    FK_ServerID,
                    max(media_set_id) as MaxMediaSetID
                from DBAdmin_Central.CentMang.backupmediaset
                group by FK_ServerID
            ) bms
                on ss.PK_ServerID = bms.FK_ServerID
            left outer join
            (
                select 
                    FK_ServerID,
                    max(backup_set_id) as MaxBackupSetID
                from DBAdmin_Central.CentMang.backupset
                group by FK_ServerID
            ) bs
                on ss.PK_ServerID = bs.FK_ServerID
        where IsOnline = 1
            and 
            (
                FK_StackID < 15
                    or FK_StackID > 15
            )
        order by ServerName
    "


    Write-Host "Get list of servers"


    $Servers = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'centralmanagement.p.db.local' `
        -Database DBADMIN_Central `
        -Query $ServerQuery `
        -QueryTimeout 20 `
        -OutputSqlErrors $True `
        -ConnectionTimeout 5 `
        -ErrorAction Continue


    Write-Host "Iterate through servers"


    #iterate through the list of servers and execute functions for each server
    Foreach ($server in $Servers)
    {
        Write-Host $server.name, $server.id


        GetBackupMediaSet $server.name $server.id $server.MaxMediaSetID        
        GetBackupMediaFamily $server.name $server.id $server.MaxMediaSetID
        GetBackupSet $server.name $server.id $server.MaxBackupSetID
        GetBackupFile $server.name $server.id $server.MaxBackupSetID
        GetBackupFileGroup $server.name $server.id $server.MaxBackupSetID                       
    }


}


function GetBackupMediaSet
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param 
        (
            [string] $server,
            [int] $serverid,
            [int] $id
        )


    Write-Host "    Get Backup Media Set"

    #query we're running
    $BMSQuery =
    "
        SELECT [media_set_id]
          ,[media_uuid]
          ,[media_family_count]
          ,[name]
          ,[description]
          ,[software_name]
          ,[software_vendor_id]
          ,[MTF_major_version]
          ,[mirror_count]
          ,[is_password_protected]
          ,[is_compressed]
          ,[is_encrypted]
      FROM [msdb].[dbo].[backupmediaset]
      where media_set_id > @id
    "

    #where we're storing query results
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable


    Write-Host "        Get Results"

    try
    {
        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='$server'; Database=DBAdmin;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=5;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()



        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = $BMSQuery
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
        $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 5
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $id


        $DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()


        $Datatable.Load($DataReader)
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "        Error Getting Backup Media Set"
        LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Get Backup Media Set for $server" $_.Exception.Message 
    }
    finally
    {
        $sqlConnection.Close()
    }





    if ($Datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Write-Host "        Insert Results"

        try
        {
            $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='centralmanagement.p.db.local'; Database=DBAdmin_Central;Trusted_Connection=True;"
            $sqlConnection.Open()


            $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
            $sqlCommand.CommandText = "[CentMang].[Insertbackupmediaset_Results]"
            $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
            $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 10
            $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $serverid
            $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@results", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Structured).value = $datatable


            $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "        Error Inserting Backup Media Set"
            LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Insert Backup Media Set for $server" $_.Exception.Message
        }
        finally
        {
            $sqlConnection.Close()    
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "        No Results"
    }
}



function GetBackupMediaFamily
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param 
        (
            [string] $server,
            [int] $serverid,
            [int] $id
        )


    Write-Host "    Get Backup Media Family"


    #query we're running
    $BMFQuery = 
    "
        SELECT [media_set_id]
          ,[family_sequence_number]
          ,[media_family_id]
          ,[media_count]
          ,[logical_device_name]
          ,[physical_device_name]
          ,[device_type]
          ,[physical_block_size]
          ,[mirror]
      FROM [msdb].[dbo].[backupmediafamily]
      where media_set_id > @id
    "


    #where we're storing query results
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable


    Write-Host "        Get Results"

    try
    {
        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='$server'; Database=DBAdmin;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=5;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()


        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = $BMFQuery
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
        $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 5
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $id


        $DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()


        $Datatable.Load($DataReader)
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "        Error Getting Backup Media Family"
        LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Get Backup Media Family for $server" $_.Exception.Message 
    }
    finally
    {
        $sqlConnection.Close()
    }


    if ($Datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Write-Host "        Insert Results"

        try
        {
        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='centralmanagement.p.db.local'; Database=DBAdmin_Central;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()


        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = "[CentMang].[Insertbackupmediafamily_Results]"
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
        $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 10
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $serverid
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@results", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Structured).value = $datatable


        $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "        Error Inserting Backup Media Family"
            LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Insert Backup Media Family for $server" $_.Exception.Message 
        }
        finally
        {            
            $sqlConnection.Close()        
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "        No Results"
    }

}


function GetBackupSet
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param 
        (
            [string] $server,
            [int] $serverid,
            [int] $id
        )


    Write-Host "    Get Backup Set"


    #query we're running
    $BSQuery = 
    "
        SELECT [backup_set_id]
          ,[backup_set_uuid]
          ,[media_set_id]
          ,[first_family_number]
          ,[first_media_number]
          ,[last_family_number]
          ,[last_media_number]
          ,[catalog_family_number]
          ,[catalog_media_number]
          ,[position]
          ,[expiration_date]
          ,[software_vendor_id]
          ,[name]
          ,[description]
          ,[user_name]
          ,[software_major_version]
          ,[software_minor_version]
          ,[software_build_version]
          ,[time_zone]
          ,[mtf_minor_version]
          ,[first_lsn]
          ,[last_lsn]
          ,[checkpoint_lsn]
          ,[database_backup_lsn]
          ,[database_creation_date]
          ,[backup_start_date]
          ,[backup_finish_date]
          ,[type]
          ,[sort_order]
          ,[code_page]
          ,[compatibility_level]
          ,[database_version]
          ,[backup_size]
          ,[database_name]
          ,[server_name]
          ,[machine_name]
          ,[flags]
          ,[unicode_locale]
          ,[unicode_compare_style]
          ,[collation_name]
          ,[is_password_protected]
          ,[recovery_model]
          ,[has_bulk_logged_data]
          ,[is_snapshot]
          ,[is_readonly]
          ,[is_single_user]
          ,[has_backup_checksums]
          ,[is_damaged]
          ,[begins_log_chain]
          ,[has_incomplete_metadata]
          ,[is_force_offline]
          ,[is_copy_only]
          ,[first_recovery_fork_guid]
          ,[last_recovery_fork_guid]
          ,[fork_point_lsn]
          ,[database_guid]
          ,[family_guid]
          ,[differential_base_lsn]
          ,[differential_base_guid]
          ,[compressed_backup_size]
          ,[key_algorithm]
          ,[encryptor_thumbprint]
          ,[encryptor_type]
      FROM [msdb].[dbo].[backupset]
      where backup_set_id > @id
    "


    #where we're storing query results
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable


    Write-Host "        Get Results"

    try
    {
        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='$server'; Database=DBAdmin;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=5;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()


        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = $BSQuery
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
        $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 5
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $id


        $DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()


        $Datatable.Load($DataReader)
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "        Error Getting Backup Set"
        LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Get Backup Set for $server" $_.Exception.Message 
    }
    finally
    {
        $sqlConnection.Close()
    }


    if ($Datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Write-Host "        Insert Results"

        try
        {
        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='centralmanagement.p.db.local'; Database=DBAdmin_Central;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()


        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = "[CentMang].[Insertbackupset_Results]"
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
        $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 10
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $serverid
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@results", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Structured).value = $datatable


        $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "        Error Inserting Backup Set"
            LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Insert Backup Set for $server" $_.Exception.Message 
        }
        finally
        {
            $sqlConnection.Close()        
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "        No Results"
    }

}


function GetBackupFile
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param 
        (
            [string] $server,
            [int] $serverid,
            [int] $id
        )


    Write-Host "    Get Backup File"


    #query we're running
    $BFQuery = 
    "
        SELECT [backup_set_id]
            ,[first_family_number]
            ,[first_media_number]
            ,[filegroup_name]
            ,[page_size]
            ,[file_number]
            ,[backed_up_page_count]
            ,[file_type]
            ,[source_file_block_size]
            ,[file_size]
            ,[logical_name]
            ,[physical_drive]
            ,[physical_name]
            ,[state]
            ,[state_desc]
            ,[create_lsn]
            ,[drop_lsn]
            ,[file_guid]
            ,[read_only_lsn]
            ,[read_write_lsn]
            ,[differential_base_lsn]
            ,[differential_base_guid]
            ,[backup_size]
            ,[filegroup_guid]
            ,[is_readonly]
            ,[is_present]
        FROM [msdb].[dbo].[backupfile]
        where backup_set_id > @id
    "


    #where we're storing query results
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable


    Write-Host "        Get Results"

    try
    {
        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='$server'; Database=DBAdmin;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=5;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()


        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = $BFQuery
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
        $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 5
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $id


        $DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()


        $Datatable.Load($DataReader)
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "        Error Getting Backup File"
        LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Get Backup File for $server" $_.Exception.Message
    }
    finally
    {
        $sqlConnection.Close()
    }


    if ($Datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Write-Host "        Insert Results"

        try
        {
            $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='centralmanagement.p.db.local'; Database=DBAdmin_Central;Trusted_Connection=True;"
            $sqlConnection.Open()


            $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
            $sqlCommand.CommandText = "[CentMang].[Insertbackupfile_Results]"
            $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
            $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 10
            $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $serverid
            $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@results", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Structured).value = $datatable


            $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "        Error Inserting Backup File"
            LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Insert Backup File for $server" $_.Exception.Message
        }
        finally
        {
            $sqlConnection.Close()   
        }     
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "        No Results"
    }


}


function GetBackupFileGroup
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param 
        (
            [string] $server,
            [int] $serverid,
            [int] $id
        )


    Write-Host "    Get Backup File Group"


    #query we're running
    $BFGQuery = 
    "
        SELECT [backup_set_id]
            ,[name]
            ,[filegroup_id]
            ,[filegroup_guid]
            ,[type]
            ,[type_desc]
            ,[is_default]
            ,[is_readonly]
            ,[log_filegroup_guid]
        FROM [msdb].[dbo].[backupfilegroup]
        where backup_set_id > '$id'
    "


    #where we're storing query results
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable


    Write-Host "        Get Results"

    try
    {
        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='$server'; Database=DBAdmin;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=5;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()


        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = $BFGQuery
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
        $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 5
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $id


        $DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()


        $Datatable.Load($DataReader)
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "        Error Getting Backup File Group"
        LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Get Backup File Group for $server" $_.Exception.Message
    }
    finally
    {
        $sqlConnection.Close()
    }


    if ($Datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Write-Host "        Insert Results"

        try
        {
        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='centralmanagement.p.db.local'; Database=DBAdmin_Central;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()


        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = "[CentMang].[Insertbackupfilegroup_Results]"
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
        $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 10
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int).value = $serverid
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@results", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Structured).value = $datatable


        $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "        Error Inserting Backup File Group"
            LogError "Get-BackupHistory" "Insert Backup File Group for $server" $_.Exception.Message
        }
        finally
        {
            $sqlConnection.Close()
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "        No Results"
    }

}


function LogError
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param 
        (
            [string] $JobName,
            [string] $JobStep,
            [string] $Error
        )


    try
    {
        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=report.p.db.local; Database=Monitor_Reporting;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()


        $sql = "
            Insert into CentMang.ErrorLog (JobName, JobStep, Error)
            values (@JobName, @JobStep, @Error)
        "
        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = $sql
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@JobName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar).value = $JobName
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@JobStep", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar).value = $JobStep
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Error", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar).value = $Error



        Write-Host "        Insert Error"
        $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "        Failed to log error"
    }
    finally
    {
        $sqlConnection.Close()
    }
}
```

Essentially, I generate a list of servers and iterate through that list.  For each server, I go out and get data from a table and save it to a data table.  I then check if there are any rows in the data table, and if there are then I insert it into our central report server.

SQL Server looks to be throwing up on checking the data table size, and I'm unsure as to why it would be doing that.  I couldn't find anything on this specific issue.

Comment: `>` operator sends output to the specified file. Hence, `$Datatable.Rows.Count > 0` is the same as  `$Datatable.Rows.Count | Out-File 0`. Maybe you want to check `$Datatable.Rows.Count -gt 0`?

Comment: @JosefZ yup, i'm an idiot, i bet that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JosefZ's comment is correct, the issue was using `>` rather than `-gt` to compare the data table.  Once I fixed that the powershell worked flawlessly.